# Reading Excel sheet column wise using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can I read a excel sheet column wise using apache poi..?(without using row Iterator)

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0);
    // Printing Stuff
}
```

I know, the above one will do the same. But I need to get first column's data without using Row Iterator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can iterate over the sheet without using iterator

```
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("file.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int j=0; j< sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0); //get first cell
        // Printing Stuff
    }
```